# Overlapping li elements with background and z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a `ul` with tree list items in an horizontal view.
All the list items have the same background image:

[image: Background image is the same for all li]

I want to overlap the background images so it looks like this:

[image: This is what I try to accomplish]

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Diabl0570/Faffz/2/)

CSS:

```
    div#menu ul li{
    height:30px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 60px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/adwVj.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right:  5px;
    padding-left:30px;
    z-index:2;        
}

div#menu ul li:first-child{
    padding-left:20px;
    z-index:3;            
}
div#menu ul li:last-child{
    padding-left:35px;    
    margin-left:-30px   
    z-index:1;       
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
       <ul>
           <li>Account</li>
           <li>Registreren</li>
           <li>Winkelwagen</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

It goes wrong with the z-index!

Comment: It's always a good idea to add some code in the question as well. Not just in the fiddle.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i added the css and html to my question

Comment: Some times we are unable to open fiddle. better keep code in question and provide fiddle link

Comment: Just out of interest, any reason for not using 2 images? Seems simpler than overlapping.

Comment: one image is less load, so i think beter. plus i thought it would be a good practice

Comment: Fair enough. Just curious as one extra image isn't going to make much of a difference load wise and you won't have to worry about any cross browser issues. +1 for the well laid out q though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should first give at least `position: relative` to your list-items, otherwise `z-index` has no effect. then just use

```
div#menu ul li + li {
   left : -20px;   
}
```

so the labels will remain close together (this rule will be applied starting from the second `<li>` element)

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Faffz/3/

Comment: thanks this works! i need to wait 3 mins before i can accept this awnser